# Can't get pymongo to connect to mongodb in jupyter notebook to run CRUD python file?

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I am running into the error that the authentication is not working for my project. I have tried a few different solutions that I found online and it still won't authenticate the user for me. I tried to write it in different ways and found similar issues on stackoverflow that had working solutions but the solutions did not work for me. I have pasted a couple of the versions that I have tried below.

The error I am currently getting is:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'authenticate' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

AnimalShelterTest.py code

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        #Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to access the MongoDB databases and collections.
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:27017")
        db = connection['AAC']
        db.authenticate(username, password)
    
#Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            insert = self.database.animals.insert(data) #data should be dictionary
        
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
            
#Create method to implement the R in CRUD.
    def read(self, searchData):
        if searchData:
            data = self.database.animals.find(searchData, {"_id": False})
        
        else:
            data = self.database.animals.find({}, {"_id": False})
        return data

#Create method to implement U in CRUD.
    def update(self, searchData, updateData):
        if searchData is not None:
            result = self.database.animals.update_many(searchData, {"$set": updateData})
        else:
            return "{}"
        return result.raw_result

#Create method to implement D in CRUD.
    def delete(self, deleteData):
        if deleteData is not None:
            result = self.database.animals.delete_many(deleteData)
        
        else:
            return "{}"
        return result.raw_result
```

.ipynb file code:

```
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash

import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import os
import numpy as np
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
import base64

#### FIX ME #####
# change animal_shelter and AnimalShelter to match your CRUD Python module file name and class name
from AnimalShelterTest import AnimalShelter





###########################
# Data Manipulation / Model
###########################
# FIX ME change for your username and password and CRUD Python module name
username = "aacuser"
password = "French"
shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)


# class read method must support return of cursor object 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))



#########################
# Dashboard Layout / View
#########################
app = JupyterDash('Project Two')

#FIX ME Add in Grazioso Salvare’s logo
image_filename = 'Grazioso_Salvare_Logo.png' # replace with your own image
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(image_filename, 'rb').read())

#FIX ME Place the HTML image tag in the line below into the app.layout code according to your design
#FIX ME Also remember to include a unique identifier such as your name or date
#html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()))

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='hidden-div', style={'display':'none'}),
    html.Center(html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()))),
    html.Center(html.B(html.H1('Dashboard'))),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(
        
#FIXME Add in code for the interactive filtering options. For example, Radio buttons, drop down, checkboxes, etc.
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='filter-type',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Water Rescue', 'value': 'WR'},
            {'label': 'Mountain or Wilderness Rescue', 'value': 'MWR'},
            {'label': 'Disaster or Individual Tracking', 'value': 'DIT'},
            {'label': 'Reset','value':'RESET'}
        ],
        value='RESET',
        labelStyle={'display':'inline-block'}
        )
    ),
   
    html.Hr(),
    dt.DataTable(
        id='datatable-id',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
#FIXME: Set up the features for your interactive data table to make it user-friendly for your client
#If you completed the Module Six Assignment, you can copy in the code you created here 
        editable=False,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable=False,
        row_selectable="single",
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Hr(),
#This sets up the dashboard so that your chart and your geolocation chart are side-by-side
    html.Div(className='row',
         style={'display' : 'flex'},
             children=[
        html.Div(
            id='graph-id',
            className='col s12 m6',

            ),
        html.Div(
            id='map-id',
            className='col s12 m6',
            )
        ])
])

#############################################
# Interaction Between Components / Controller
#############################################


@app.callback([Output('datatable-id','data'),
               Output('datatable-id','columns')],
              [Input('filter-type', 'value')])
def update_dashboard(filter_type):
### FIX ME Add code to filter interactive data table with MongoDB queries

        if filter_type == 'WR':
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Female'},
                                                         {'$or': [
                                                             {'breed': 'Labrador Retriever Mix'},
                                                             {'breed': 'Chesa Bay Retr Mix'},
                                                             {'breed': 'Newfoundland Mix'},
                                                             {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Labrador Retriever'},
                                                             {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Australian Cattle Dog'},
                                                             {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Great Pyrenees'}]
                                                         },
                                                         {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 26}},
                                                                  {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 156}}]
                                                         }]
                                                })))
        elif filter_type == 'MWR':
            #Grazioso breeds and ages
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Male'},
                                                          {'$or': [
                                                              {'breed': 'German Shepherd'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Alaskan Malamute'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Old English Sheepdog'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Rottweiler'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Siberian Husky'}]
                                                          },
                                                          {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 26}},
                                                                    {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 156}}]
                                                          }]
                                                })))
        #adjusts the read request for the desired dog type and status
        elif filter_type == 'DRIT':
            #breeds and ages
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Male'},
                                                          {'$or': [
                                                              {'breed': 'Doberman Pinscher'},
                                                              {'breed': 'German Shepherd'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Golden Retriever'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Bloodhound'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Rottweiler'}]
                                                          },
                                                          {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 20}},
                                                                    {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 300}}]
                                                          }]
                                                })))
        #resets the search no filter
        elif filter_type == 'RESET':
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))

        
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns]
        data=df.to_dict('records')
        
        return (data,columns)




@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-id', 'style_data_conditional'),
    [Input('datatable-id', 'selected_columns')]
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]

@app.callback(
    Output('graph-id', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-id', "derived_viewport_data")])
def update_graphs(viewData):
    ###FIX ME ####
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(viewData)
    names = dff['breed'].value_counts().keys().tolist()
    values = dff['breed'].value_counts().tolist()
    # add code for chart of your choice (e.g. pie chart) #
    return [
        dcc.Graph(            
            figure = px.pie(
                data_frame = dff,
                values = values,
                names = names,
                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu,
                width = 800,
                height = 500
            )
        )    
    ]

@app.callback(
    Output('map-id', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-id', "derived_viewport_data"),
     Input('datatable-id', 'selected_rows'),
    Input('datatable-id', 'selected_columns')])
def update_map(viewData, selected_rows, selected_columns):
#FIXME: Add in the code for your geolocation chart
#If you completed the Module Six Assignment, you can copy in the code you created here.
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(viewData)
    
    if selected_rows == []:
        selected_rows = [0]
        
    # Austin TX is at [30.75, -97.48]
    if len(selected_rows) == 1:
        return [
            dl.Map(style={'width':'1000px', 'height': '500px'}, center=[30.75,-97.48], zoom=10, children=[
                dl.TileLayer(id="base-layer-id"),
            
                #marker with tool tip and popup
                dl.Marker(position=[(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],13]), (dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],14])], children=[
                    dl.Tooltip(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],4]),
                    dl.Popup([
                        html.H4("Animal Name"),
                        html.P(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],9]),
                        html.H4("Sex"),
                        html.P(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],12]),
                        html.H4("Breed"),
                        html.P(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],4]),
                        html.H4("Age"),
                        html.P(dff.iloc[selected_rows[0],15])
                    ])
                ])
            ])
        ]


app
```

Here is the full error code I am getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 32
     30 username = "aacuser"
     31 password = "French"
---> 32 shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
     35 # class read method must support return of cursor object 
     36 df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))

File ~\Sample Python Code\7-2 Project Two files\AnimalShelterTest.py:13, in AnimalShelter.__init__(self, username, password)
     11 connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:27017")
     12 db = connection['AAC']
---> 13 connection.api.authenticate(username, password)

File C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py:3200, in Collection.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3198 """This is only here so that some API misusages are easier to debug."""
   3199 if "." not in self.__name:
-> 3200     raise TypeError(
   3201         "'Collection' object is not callable. If you "
   3202         "meant to call the '%s' method on a 'Database' "
   3203         "object it is failing because no such method "
   3204         "exists." % self.__name
   3205     )
   3206 raise TypeError(
   3207     "'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to "
   3208     "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' object it is "
   3209     "failing because no such method exists." % self.__name.split(".")[-1]
   3210 )

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'authenticate' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

I originally had the AnimalShelterTest.py code to pull the database using

```
self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/' % (username, password))
self.database = self.client['AAC']
```

and this gave me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 32
     30 username = "aacuser"
     31 password = "French"
---> 32 shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
     35 # class read method must support return of cursor object 
     36 df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))

File ~\Sample Python Code\7-2 Project Two files\AnimalShelter.py:11, in AnimalShelter.__init__(self, username, password)
      9 def __init__(self, username, password):
     10     #Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to access the MongoDB databases and collections.
---> 11     self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/' % (username, password))
     12     #where xxxx is your unique port number
     13     self.database = self.client['AAC']

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Does this work? `self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % (username, password))`  See the [example](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/authentication.html?highlight=authenticate#percent-escaping-username-and-password) in the docs.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried and it gives me the same error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/'format.(username, password))
```

this alteration fixed my problem

Comment: Are you sure? `'mongodb://localhost:27017/'format.(username, password)` isn't syntactically correct python.

Comment: @rickhg12hs yeah, I’m not sure what went wrong during installation to make this be the working solution but when I googled my error it brought me here (https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting/ ) and I tried the formatting solution and it worked. The full program isn’t running correctly but I figured I can make some edits to see what else needs to be changed